# Login keeps directing the user to the login page despite correct login data

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, ejs

I built the login route using passport, there are a few issues with the validation rules and being directed to a specific page after logging in.

Login POST:

```
app.post(
  '/login',
  [
    body('email').custom((value) => {
      if (!value.includes('@gmail') && !value.includes('@hotmail') && !value.includes('@icloud')) {
        throw new Error('Invalid email domain. Only Gmail, Hotmail, and iCloud domains are allowed.');
      }
      return true; // Indicates validation success
    }),
    body('password').notEmpty(),
  ],
  async (req, res, next) => {
    // Validate the request using express-validator
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    // Check if there are validation errors for email
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).send(errors.array()[0].msg);
    }

    // Authenticate user using passport-local strategy
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      // Check if authentication failed
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(401).send('Incorrect email or password');
      } else if(user){
        req.redirect("/home");
      }

      // Authentication successful, check if password is correct
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (bcryptErr, result) => {
        if (bcryptErr) {
          return next(bcryptErr);
        }

        

        // Password is correct, log in the user and redirect to MyAccount
        req.login(user, (loginErr) => {
          if (loginErr) {
            return next(loginErr);
          }
          return res.redirect('/views/MyAccount');
        });
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  }
);
```

Passport Strategy Code:

```
    passport.use(new Strategy( async function verify(email, password, cb){
console.log("Passport.use email:",email);
console.log("Verifying User:" +email)

    try {

      const result = await db.query("SELECT * FROM DONORS WHERE email = $1", [email]);
      if (result.rows.length > 0){
        const donor = result.rows[0];
        const storedHashedPassword = donor.password;
        bcrypt.compare(password, storedHashedPassword, (err, result) => {
          if(err){
            // console.error("Error comparing passwords");
            return cb(err);
          } else{
            if (result){
              // res.render("/views/MyAccount.ejs");
              return cb(null, donor)
            } else {
              // res.send("Incorrect password");
              return cb(null, false)
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        // res.send("User not found")
        return cb("User not found")
      }
      
    } catch (error) {
      return cb(err)
    }


}));
```

Despite entering correct login data, the user is directed to a page that says
'Incorrect email or password'
I'm not sure if the problem is with the order of the code or the logic itself